# How to use an alternative promise library in VueJs project?

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, promise

- **Device**: PC
- **Browser**: Chrome (62.0.3202.94)
- **OS**: Ubuntu 16.04

Hey! I'm using VueJs webpack starter. I've tried many things, but nothing seems to work — browser keeps using its native promise library. Here are some things I did (tried DefinePlugin, ProvidePlugin, explicit shadowing):

---

**webpack.base.conf.js**:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  'Promise': 'bluebird',
  'window.Promise': 'bluebird',
  'global.Promise': 'bluebird'
})
```

When I do `console.log(Promise === window.Promise)` I get `false`

---

**webpack.base.conf.js**:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'Promise': 'bluebird',
  'window.Promise': 'bluebird',
  'global.Promise': 'bluebird'
})
```

When I do `console.log(Promise === window.Promise)` I get `false`

---

**app.component.js**

```
import Bluebird from 'bluebird'
window.Promise = Bluebird
global.Promise = Bluebird
```

When I do `console.log(Promise === window.Promise)` I get `false`

---

I just discovered it only works if I add a script to `index.html`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bluebird/3.5.1/bluebird.core.js"></script>
```

Any advice? How to replace a promise library from inside config files (without `index.html` modification)?

Comment: `window.promise` , should that be `window.Promise`  If you import in your app make sure you [import from](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/) `bluebird/js/browser`, the package.json will point to `js/release/bluebird.js`

Comment: @HMR, hey, thank you! Unfortunately, it still doesn't work. When I try `console.log(window.Promise === Promise)` on a page without webpack I get `true`. In Vue app the same line gives me `false`. It means Vue app has a wrapper for global functions or something like that. So, it's impossible to shadow native `Promise` from inside an app like that.